# Class not being added with jQuery input check

Tags: jquery, submit

me again,

Im using:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.check').submit(function() {

    var abort = false;

        $('.required').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val()==='') {
              $(this).addClass(' error');
              abort = true;
            }
        })
        return abort;
        })
});
</script>
```

Example HTML

```
<form class="check" style="font-family: Arial;" action="contact.php" method="post">
<input class="wipe required" style="font-family: Arial;" type="text" name="name" value="Full Name" />
<more input fields as above>
<more input fields as above>
<more input fields as above>
<more input fields as above>
<input class="right" style="font-family: Arial;" type="submit" value="SEND" /></form>
```

which will be part of a larger form validation, however the error class isn't being added (despite not filling in the fields with a required class). The form just tries to submit - if i add event.preventDefault(); then the form doesn't submit but still the error class isn't added?

The jQuery is added before the  tag

Comment: You need to show your html too and where you are putting this script.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: added example, just a standard form.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the class works fine but your `return` logic is backwards.

If you want to prevent the submit you need to return `false` ... or call `event.preventDefault()`

```js
 $('.check').submit(function() {

    var proceed = true;

    $('.required').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === '') {
        $(this).addClass(' error');
        proceed = false;
      }
    });   
    return proceed;
  });
```

```css
.error {  
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="check" style="font-family: Arial;" action="contact.php" method="post">
  <input class="wipe required" style="font-family: Arial;" type="text" name="name" value="Full Name" />
  <input class="wipe required" style="font-family: Arial;" type="text" name="age" value="" />
  <input class="right" style="font-family: Arial;" type="submit" value="SEND" />
</form>
```

Comment: the return logic was because i was thinking in my head do you need to abort the submission yes / no as such as opposed to the logic behind it. However I still can't get the error class to be added for some reason.

Comment: Provide a demo that reproduces it. Are you sure the class isn't being added fine but the css rule(s) you use isn't specific enough to see visual changes when it is added?

Comment: positive, as i'm checking with the web inspector.

Comment: Clearly works in snippet above. Something different then in what you are using vs what you are showing us. Or the form is reloading page or some other behavior not mentioned

Comment: I'm having to use the code editor of a bespoke CMS so im wondering if something is awry there or conflicting somehow?

Comment: If I insert alerts rather than adding a class it works oddly.

Comment: No way to help without a lot more details and a [mcve]

Comment: I can appreciate that. Will see if i can get a non working version up.